# How to concatenate variables in jquery

Tags: ajax, jquery

```
var f="http://";
var s=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
var t="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/getmore.php";
var last=f+s+t;
    $.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url  : last
    ...
    ....
   });
```

Its not working... please help me!!!

Comment: you need to echo and quote your var s="<? echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>";

Comment: looks like your var s is trying to use a PHP variable assignment in javascript.

Comment: Why do you need `f` and `s` at all?

Comment: The whole ajax script is not working due to php script var s="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>"...

Comment: Is there any alternate way for retrieving  var s="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>"  in jquer/ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved it myself and the right answer is

```
var f="http://";
var s= location.host;
var t="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/getmore.php";
var lastres=f+s+t;
```

Thanks evedybody for supporting me!!!

Answer (score 4):

`final` is reserved word you can't use it as variable

```
var final1=f+s+t;
```

and

```
var s="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>";
```

as `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];` is php code

Comment: OP using `last` not `final`

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote your $_SERVER variable like this.Also `final` is a reserved keyword.use something else.

```
var s= '<?php echo $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] ?>';
```

Answer (score 0):

use `PHP` tags arount your `PHP` code

```
var f="http://";
var s="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>";
var t="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/getmore.php";
var final=f+s+t;
$.ajax({
type : "POST",
url  : final
...
....
});
```

And you might as well change the "final" to other word.

Answer (score 0):

You also have syntax error for `var s;`

correct syntax is as below,

```
var s="<? echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>";
```

Comment: I cannot find last here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

Comment: @mplungjan Yeah Sir...I have edited answer after seeing your link...Thanks..learned new thing today

Answer (score 0):

use php code to get the server name

```
var s = "<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>";
```